# Writing a randomforest model in a MYSQL DB

Tags: r

I have a situation where I create a random forest model in R language and store that model object into a MySQL DB. 
I tried to serialize the R object and store it under a column of type blob. I am able to do an insert table in SQL but when I try to read it back and unserialize, it gives the following error msg.

> ob<-unserialize(read_obj) Error in unserialize(read_obj) :
>   'connection' must be a connection

Can any one help on this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apparently you are passing the wrong thing to the `unserialize` function. If you posted a more complete example of your current code, it might be easier to identify what you should actually pass there.